# Automatic detection of old answers that might need updating

Tags: discussion, edits, old-answers

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618543/6162307) today and edited it. Originally it look like this:

```
[x for _,x in sorted(zip(Y,X))]
```

And that was it, no explanation or any comments of any kind. Now I know that the question only asked for the *"..shortest code.."* but still it could be more elaborate for the *greater good*..

Anyway, the top comment on this answer had **78** upvotes and was posted after the last time the answer was edited (before my edit today that is).

That got me thinking that we could have an algorithm that searches for cases like that (accepted answers with a last-edit date older than a *very popular* comment) and *flag* them as **"requiring edit"**. In my mind, the chances that this comment is discussing a feature not addressed by the question are *very high*.

I would like to hear your thoughts on this. Also if you feel that my edit deteriorated the quality of the question I would love to talk about that too.

Thanks!

Comment: We get lots of "not an answer" flags on old, inadequate answers like this. Please send me your email address, and I will forward you a list of them so you can go through and improve them all.

Comment: @CodyGray define _lots_ first.. xD

Comment: If only the Edit Rep farmer could have you teaching them how to make edit... So will be saved in one day! You did a good job.

Comment: it sounds like you only need some [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) kung-fu, someone surely can pass a nice answer that finds these.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I wish I could do that alone but I am a stranger to the _meta-ways_. I believe that if we set the threshold of the comment upvotes _high enough_ we could prevent being flooded with update-requests. On the other hand we would be leaving out topics that do not attract much attention but it is still better than nothing.

Comment: I have pinged some peps that have fun with SEDE, with some patience hopefully they will also enjoy adding a query to find your answers (To get SE to implement would take 6-8 in very long time unit). It could be useful to define *"very popular"*, how many upvotes do you consider very popular?

Comment: @PetterFriberg Maybe we could define it based on the answer's score. Like a third of whatever the answer has? I do not know really but it feels better than a constant number and we will be able to calibrate that based on the query results. On a second though, given that this is SQL I could also give it a shot.

Comment: *go go go, show some code attempt :D* @Ev.Kounis if you have doubts enter [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ping [rene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene). He is always happy to get pinged ;), it makes him less blurry!

Comment: I was going to vote this up before I realize that you wrote "detection" instead of "deletion"

Comment: according to me the answers of a question most suits to the day which is asked. Seeing that answer years after may seem ridiculous. An option to mark such answers is more legitimate than updating the answer. The most suitable answer can be added as new answer also

Comment: You can make code-block-links?? Well I just learned something. Also that's a fantastic edit, please feel free to find more answers like that and edit them! :D

Comment: Nice idea, but browsing throught he list in the answer it seems like most of these simply don't need edits.

Comment: Is it only me to whom the idea of editing question like this looks weird? Sure, an improvement, you are adding 99% more to highly-voted question.. but if you scroll down - you will see **another** answer, which does exactly same. Why don't you edit it to add explanation? Or shall we delete other answers? Or what? If you see outdated/incorrect answer - simply post a new/correct one, or just downvote it and add comment. It's enough for other people. P.S.: don't know python, can't judge (or rollback) here.

Comment: @Sinatr I totally get what you are saying. As you say, the issues raised in a comment in the accepted answers might be addressed by another answer further down. Collecting all knowledge in a single answer is not optimal. The issue to be discussed then is moved from my concerns to the way SO orders the answers of a question with OP having a supervote, etc.. That makes the idea of posting a new answer in an old question not lucrative enough..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, isn't the answer of [1-ijk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29066554/1997232) already using lambda, which you decide to add to answer by only using criteria "it's accepted and highly voted, let's edit it"? *"Collecting all knowledge in a single answer is not optimal"* - but this is what you are doing, no? Btw, I am not against long detailed answers, I simply don't understand why don't you post own answer, why editing other answers? If your answer is better it will eventually get upvoted (while answer lacking details may even gets downvoted as time passes).

Comment: @Sinatr Well, because the thoughts I just shared with you came after the edit. What you propose would work if the accepted answer was not treated like GOD by SO. The way things are now, I do not see the point.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to find these posts yourself (which is probably a better idea than waiting for Stack Exchange to implement it), here's a Data Explorer query to get you started...

[Posts where a comment with a score >= 50 was posted after the last edit and there was no comment posted with a score >= 50 before that comment](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/713365/887840/):

```sql
select top 50 p.Id as [Post Link]
from Comments c
join Posts p on c.PostId = p.Id
left join Comments c2 on c2.PostId = c.PostId and c2.CreationDate < c.CreationDate and c2.Score >= 50
where c.Score >= 50 and p.LastEditDate < c.CreationDate and c2.Id is null
group by c.Id, p.Id
```

Does it make sense to have the "there was no comment posted with a score >= 50 before that comment" criteria in there? How would it change the results? No idea, but it's easy enough to remove the "left join" if you don't want it there.

I personally don't really think this would be as useful as you seem to think (on the assumption that highly upvoted comments are often just tangential as opposed to pointing out a problem), but I could be wrong.

---

I initially thought you were looking for [short posts (<= 50 characters) containing only code](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/713358/887831/):

```sql
select top 50 Id as [Post Link], Body, Score
from Posts
where Body like '<pre><code>%</code></pre>_'
and Body not like '<pre><code>%<code>%</code></pre>_' /* this makes sense for longer bodies */
and len(Body) < 50
and CommunityOwnedDate is null
order by Score desc /* remove this for faster queries */
```

Those seem like good candidates for editing.

---

Note: `ParentId is null` gives you questions only.

Comment: 658 rows returned when removing `top 50`. Yet, it may not worth an "_automation_" being done for such impact. Thanks Dukeling for the _manual_ solution.

Comment: I randomly clicked about 8 of these, and none needed an edit. Therefore this is not a simple list that can be 'worked away' by random attempts. Perhaps someone can go through all of them (or one part and indicate how people can proceed).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I "randomly" clicked the first 7 of those, and 4/7 can probably do with an edit to address or incorporate the comment (the 3 misses are a question, a non-top non-accepted answer, which can probably be edited too, and a wiki post, the 4 hits are the only accepted answers). I'm leaning towards my initial suspicions being wrong. Keep in mind that comments should be considered temporary and any important information should ideally be edited into posts instead of just being in the comments.

Comment: I checked some of these answers and I'm surprised how well this works! Many comments saying "This answer is outdated/from version X onwards use [this]"

Comment: @Dukeling Optimising the query to yield only accepted answers would improve the quality of the list imho. I forked your query. Take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this query is as good as it can be but it succeeds in just returning *accepted answers*.

```sql
SELECT p1.AcceptedAnswerId AS [Post Link] FROM 
(SELECT AcceptedAnswerId FROM Posts WHERE AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL) p1 
JOIN Posts p2 ON p1.AcceptedAnswerId = p2.Id
JOIN Comments c ON c.PostID = p2.Id 
WHERE c.Score > 50 AND p2.LastEditDate < c.CreationDate
```

More specifically, it returns a list of all those accepted answers that have a last edit date older than the top comment which in turn has a score bigger than 50. This returns 344 results which are not *too many*.

The first results yielded are these:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp/12052#12052)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473/how-can-i-undo-git-reset-hard-head1/21778#21778)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses/53500#53500)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611/javascript-private-methods/55637#55637)

I am not so familiar with `C#`, `git`, `regex`, `javascript` (what can I really...) so I cannot judge how effective this is based on those but it does not look too bad to me..

Comment: Only looked at the first one there. I *could* see a reason for that comment to be edited into the answer (or made into a new answer). It's very valid and on-point with the question's original intent.